# PHP prints sqlite query as plaintext

Tags: php, sqlite

My problem is, that on one server the following sqlite query will work and on another server, the sqlite query is printet out as plain text.

the code looks like:

```
<?

$db = new SQLite3("../data/data.db");

if (!empty($_POST['inputDateTime']) && !empty($_POST['inputShortName']) && !empty($_POST['textareaBreakingnews']))
{

    $received_date = $_POST['inputDateTime'];
    $received_short_name = mb_strtoupper($_POST['inputShortName']);
    $received_breaking_news = $_POST['textareaBreakingnews'];

    $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO news (news_text, date_created, callback_person) VALUES ('$received_breaking_news', '$received_date', '$received_short_name')");


    if ($query)
    {
        echo "News were added.";
    }
    else
    {
        die(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"));
    }
}
```

the result is the following:

> query("INSERT INTO news (news_text, date_created, callback_person) VALUES ('$received_breaking_news', '$received_date', '$received_short_name')"); if ($query) { echo "News were added."; } else { die(header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")); } }

in the xampp configuration sqlite and sqlite3 are enabled and there is no problem to read the sqlite database.

I think there is one litte thing, that I have overlook.

Comment: `<?` chang that to `<?php` maybe its short open settings in your php.ini

Comment: thanks a lot I figured it out as I read the similar question added on the top ^^